# CSS Button and Image Behind

Tags: html, css

Sorry there isn't more code on this. I am new and stumped to be honest.

I have a CSS Button I am using on my webpage, code below. I'd like to put an image around the button like below... Slightly off center,behind the button itself, and which is mobile responsive.

```css
.redbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  padding: 15px 6px 15px 6px;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: #faddde;
  border: solid 1px #980c10;
  background: #d81b21;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ed1c24), to(#aa1317));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ed1c24, #aa1317);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ed1c24', endColorstr='#aa1317');
}

.largebuttonwidthC {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="redbutton largebuttonwidthC">SHOW ME HOW</div>
```

The circle image is here:

[image: button circle]

And I'd like it to look like this:

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

[image: behind the button like this]

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.contain {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb7M7.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 60%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.redbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  padding: 15px 6px 15px 6px;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: #faddde;
  border: solid 1px #980c10;
  background: #d81b21;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ed1c24), to(#aa1317));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ed1c24, #aa1317);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ed1c24', endColorstr='#aa1317');
}

.largebuttonwidthC {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="redbutton largebuttonwidthC">SHOW ME HOW</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/nf7b2zx1/

```css
.redbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  padding: 15px 6px 15px 6px;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  ;
  color: #faddde;
  background: #d81b21;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb7M7.png) no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ed1c24', endColorstr='#aa1317');
}

.largebuttonwidthC {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px
}
```

```html
<div class="redbutton largebuttonwidthC">IAM TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but I guess you will see the idea behind: [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt23wg1z/9/)

```css
.redbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 50px;
  padding: 15px 6px 15px 6px;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: #faddde;
  border: solid 1px #980c10;
  background: #d81b21;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ed1c24), to(#aa1317));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ed1c24, #aa1317);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ed1c24', endColorstr='#aa1317');
}

.largebuttonwidthC {
  width: 300px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}

.image {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -30px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb7M7.png') no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 512px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="redbutton largebuttonwidthC">SHOW ME HOW</div>
  <span class="image"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should clean your CSS and optimize it by not duplicating arguments such as "cursor: pointer", which you ca find two times in the code, also the "outline: none" should only be when the button is focused or active.

Either way, to put an image in the background you should do something similar to :

```
<button class="my_button" type="">My amazing button</button>

.my_button {
/*height, width, color...*/

background-image: url(img/my_img.png);
/* You can even move the image in the background to better suit your needs*/
background-position-y:-50px; /* Move the image on the Y axes*/
background-position-x: 10px; /* Move the image on the X axes*/
background-size: cover;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to something like this.

```css
.redbutton {
        display: inline-block;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
        padding: 15px 6px 15px 6px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;    
        cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb7M7.png) no-repeat;
        filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ed1c24', endColorstr='#aa1317');    
    }
    .largebuttonwidthC{
        width: 535px;
        min-height:150px;
    }
    .redbutton p{
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 35px;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
        width: 470px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="redbutton largebuttonwidthC">
 <p>Click Here to instantly Download this file</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the buttons background to that blue circle

background-image: url(you img here...);

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of CSS you can get something similar

```
.redbutton:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;
    right:-20px;
    top:-20px;
    bottom:-20px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb7M7.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```